# Screen Validation, JPA validation and hashed passwords

Tags: java, jpa

I'm validating a user password using an `@Pattern` regex.

That works fine, but then I hash the password, which results in a password of much more than the 16 characters my validation has specified.

However this validation rule is filtering down to my JPA layer, so my hashed password is far too long for the validation rule, and I get a 'Validation failed for....' message when I try to persist my object.

Sure I'm missing something fundamental, but what is it?

Thanks

Comment: Basically, I only want the validation to take place at the presentation layer, forgot to say that. How do I turn it off at the persistence layer?

Comment: Just a note: You can edit your question if you need to. Just press the "edit" link under the tags.

Comment: Aside: why would you want a maximum length on passwords? Any restrictions on password content will at best annoy people who know how entropy works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a typical scenario, and the solutions are two:

- use DTOs - objects that are not PA entities and are used to transfer data from the web layer to the service layer. So you place the regex validation only on the DTO, and not the entity
- have a `@Transient` field `repeatPassword` and place the validation there, rather than on the one that gets persisted in the DB.

In short - you shouldn't have the annotation on your actual password field of the entity. Turning off validation for the persistence layer is an option, but is not preferred as it may lead to a lot of side-effects.

Comment: Ahh, thanks that makes sense. I'm using Roo to generate all my entity classes so was hoping to avoid DTOs. I've got a transient field ('confirmPassword') so I'll stick the validation there. Will report back asap- thanks a million

Comment: Yep, thanks for that, was going a bit crazy. Makes perfect sense too. Cheers!

Comment: Just to clarify, I've got a password field that gets passed from the form as plain text. I then hash it, resulting in a long string. That field has no validation on it. I also have a 'confirmPassword' field on my entity (also from the form) but I dont persist it so its marked as transient. That's the field I have the @Pattern validation on. Works well.